# Only Unity 8 in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: unity, uninstall, lightdm, unity8

I would keep on my ubuntu 16.10 freesh install only the unity 8 desktop and remove Unity 7 and all relative apps. I've removed **unity** (apt-get remove unity && apt-get autoremove) but after login I have only a white mouse coursor on black wallpaper.

Thanks.

Comment: The Unity 8 session which can be installed in 16.10 is only a preview. It's really not recommended to be the only one you have installed (or it'd be the default already if it were).